# Convert iteration to map

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got the following code:

```
@classmethod
def load(self):
    with open('yaml/instruments.yaml', 'r') as ymlfile:
        return {v['name']: Instrument(**v) for (v) in list(yaml.load_all(ymlfile))}
```

I'd like to load these in parallel using something like:

```
return ThreadPoolExecutor.map(Instrument, list(yaml.load_all(ymlfile))
```

But I'm not quite sure how to get the parameters to pass.

Here's an example of instruments.yaml:

```
---
    name: 'corn'
    #Trade December corn only
    multiplier: 5000
    contract_prefix: 'C'
    months_traded: [3, 5, 7, 9, 12]
    quandl: 'CHRIS/CME_C2'
    first_contract: 196003
    backtest_from: 199312
    trade_only: [12]
    contract_name_prefix: 'C'
    quandl_database: 'CME'
    slippage: 0.125 #half the spread
    ib_code: 'ZC'
```

How do I refactor my code as a map so I can use ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: You do understand that `ThreadPoolExecutor` (and threads in general) are not very useful for work that is CPU bound (aside from stuff with heavy data processing third party libraries that release [the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GIL)), right? Unless `Instrument` is some C extension type (or spends a lot of time on I/O), threading this won't gain you anything. Also, `for (v) in list(yaml.load_all(ymlfile))` is almost certainly better expressed as `for v in yaml.load_all(ymlfile)`, which avoids unnecessary conversion to `list` when you'll just iterate it and throw it away anyway.

Comment: Load operates in two stages (which are separable)- each one loads around 1000 CSV files into pandas dataframes, and step 2 performs some basic calculations (moving averages). Each load takes around 30-60 seconds when run on my intel i3; or about 15 minutes for the full dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is to define a top level simple worker function for use in the executor:

```
def make_instrument_pair(d):
    return d['name'], Instrument(**d)
```

Then change:

```
@classmethod
def load(self):
    with open('yaml/instruments.yaml', 'r') as ymlfile:
        return {v['name']: Instrument(**v) for (v) in list(yaml.load_all(ymlfile))}
```

to:

```
@classmethod
def load(self):
    with open('yaml/instruments.yaml') as ymlfile,\
         concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
        return dict(executor.map(make_instrument_pair, yaml.load_all(ymlfile)))
```

As I noted in my comments, this probably won't gain you anything; [the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GIL) means that threads don't improve performance unless:

1. The work is done in third party C extensions that explicitly release the GIL before doing a lot of C level work
2. The work is mostly I/O bound (or otherwise spends most of its time blocking in some way, whether it's sleeping, waiting on locks, etc.)

Unless `Instrument` is really expensive to construct, even using `ProcessPoolExecutor` likely won't help; you need to do a meaningful amount of work in the tasks dispatched, or you're wasting more time on task management (and for processes, serialization and interprocess communication) than you gain in parallelism.